# Close voter has a problem

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

This thread may be a typical problem. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763221/does-selenium-support-switching-bewteen-windows) question. In this question, OP asking about Selenium testing, not asking about String comparison.This question has some writing problems but it's pretty legit. OP supports what he did. But one of the user marks close vote for duplicate reason.I think the close voter did not read the question carefully or he don't understand Selenium. This may be misunderstanding for other users. so what we do that kind of close voter?

Comment: Great you posted that, I could hammer it. It is most definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @Tunaki You action is right .You explained that error is not related with selenium,just coding error before you closed this post. I think ever close voter should do likes that.

Comment: As a side-note, you are directly targeting a user with your question, implying that they "have a problem", that it is a "typical problem" and that they should be taken care of. This is not the thought-process you should have: if a user found it was a duplicate of a question, you should ask yourself why they did so because they certainly have a reason. Sometimes, the question is read too quickly and the dupe is inappropriate I agree. I would hope that more often than not, it is not the case though. You should default to "hmm why did someone think it was a dupe of that? Let me read the Q again".

Comment: @Tunaki lol I just sympathize some new OPs, that's why I ask this on Meta. Some OPs expect great answers for their questions. They post their codes and ask as much as they can. But some treat they are noob. They close question without explanation. I understand OPs may be ask a question wrong way. But we can correct them with simple explanation or comment. :)

Comment: @sai ye yang naing aye too many new users, too many crap questions. The situation you describe is of course the ideal one. In a site like SO,receiving thousands of crap questions a day... Not scalable. People who aren't paid tend to prefer challenging questions on code rather than argue endlessly with OPs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question title is misleading. The asker claims that there is a problem with Selenium, when in reality they've simply fallen into the well-worn trap of comparing two Java strings using the equality/inequality operator.

Evidently, there are two possible ways to handle this question:

1. Answer it, telling the asker that this *isn't* a Selenium issue but simply a string comparison issue and linking to the the Java string comparison question.
2. Mark it as a duplicate of the Java string comparison question.

Whether you consider #2 as a valid resolution depends on your definition of "duplicate".

In my opinion, this isn't a high quality question anyway and we aren't losing anything by turning it into a signpost for the asker. Again, as mentioned, there isn't actually an issue with Selenium as the title seems to imply. If someone is so inclined, they could edit the title to be less misleading.

Comment: Your answer is appropriate. The close voter can comment what is wrong in OP's coding and it is not related with Selenium or something likes that.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye People *did* comment on the question explaining why the duplicate question answers the question.